# Is there a Javascript "tap" event library that uses event delegation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch

Ideally I can do `$(document.body).on("tap", "#myElement", this.eventHandler);`

But jQuery hasn't done that yet.

I see so many libraries -- https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Touch. There's a long list on that page.

They all seem to use old fashioned event listening. Such as, `$("#element").touchLibraryThingy(); $("#element").bind("tap")`. Equivalent to `addEventListener`.

That's great for an ID (Sorta), but when I have 50 list items that all have events on them, I don't want someone on an old Android to have 50 event listeners. For performance reasons!

Does anyone know of a library that uses event delegation that is *finished*?

This stackoverflow question is similar but doesn't come to truth -- [Extend jQuery's .on() to work with mobile touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311079/extend-jquerys-on-to-work-with-mobile-touch-events)

Comment: Please see this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314450/jquery-how-to-capture-the-tab-keypress-within-a-textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better yet, now with jQuery Mobile custom builder, you can only select their mobile events and get the latest touch code, which has improvements over the example above.

http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the blob mentioned in the post [Extend jQuery's .on() to work with mobile touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311079/extend-jquerys-on-to-work-with-mobile-touch-events) actually does the trick... almost.

Link to library! https://github.com/jvduf/jquery-mobile-events/blob/master/jquery.mobile.events.js

**The gotcha**
"tap" on desktop doesn't prevent default it seems. I had odd scrolling behavior and choppy menu animation in my web app.

To fix this I created a global property inside my app's namespace:

```
var R = window.R = window.R || {};
R.touchEvent = ('ontouchstart' in window') ? "tap" : "click";
window.$body = $(document.body);
```

Then all my event listeners do this:

```
$body.on(R.touchEvent, ".myHellaLongListItems", this.eventHandler);
```

Done! Now we all can have a really nice mobile website.